# JQ: how can I remove keys based on regex?

Tags: json, jq

I would like to remove all keys that start with "hide". Important to note that the keys may be nested at many levels. I'd like to see the answer using a regex, although I recognise that in my example a simple `contains` would suffice. (I don't know how to do this with `contains`, either, BTW.)

Input JSON 1:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "hideA": 3,
  "c": {
    "d": 4,
    "hide4": 5
  }
}
```

Desired output JSON:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": {
    "d": 4
  }
}
```

Input JSON 2:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "hideA": 3,
  "c": {
    "d": 4,
    "hide4": 5
  },
  "e": null,
  "f": "hiya",
  "g": false,
  "h": [{
    "i": 343.232,
    "hide9": "private",
    "so_smart": true
  }]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward approach to the problem is to use `walk` in conjunction with `with_entries`, e.g.

```
walk(if type == "object" 
     then with_entries(select(.key | test("^hide") | not))
     else . end)
```

If your jq does not have `walk/1` simply include its def (available e.g. from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedolan/jq/master/src/builtin.jq) before invoking it.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're just checking the start of the keys, you could use `startswith/1` instead in this case, otherwise you could use `test/1` or `test/2`. Then you could pass those paths to be removed to `delpaths/1`.

You might want to filter the key by strings (or convert to strings) beforehand to account for arrays in your tree.

```
delpaths([paths | select(.[-1] | strings | startswith("hide"))])
```

```
delpaths([paths | select(.[-1] | strings | test("^hide"; "i"))])
```

Comment: Thanks. I had been trying with `del`. And the `.[-1]` syntax is new to me. And even the use case of `paths` was a mystery to me.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `test/1` and `test/2`, don't see these referenced in the documentation or tutorial.

Comment: All the regex functions come in 1 and 2 argument variants. The second is typically for setting additional flags (such as `g` for global matches or `i` for case-insensitive matches). Check the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) for all the functions available.

Comment: I'm facing a problem here with a new JSON input (see edited question). The problem is caused by `true`, `false` and `null` values, as well as the  array found at key `h`. Any ideas?

Comment: The values should have no effect on the result here since we're filtering based on the path. However we do need to restrict the paths to scalars (and not just all possible paths). Without it, the paths to array values will also be returned and the index `0` cannot be tested as a string (without a conversion). Since we're testing specifically for property names, we can ignore them.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it, it might be better to not filter to scalars in general. You might want to hide an object or array and using scalars will skip them.